# How to sent list using CommandParameter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a ListView and since it supports multiple selection I have a button where I gather all the SelectedItems and pass them using CommandParameter. Being very new to this I really don't know how to do so with parameters. How do I access the list when it has been passed to my ViewModel? Please see below code:

### View

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView"  ItemsSource="{Binding myModel.myCollection}">
<Button Command="{Binding SelectBtnOnClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=ListView}">
```

### ViewModel

```
public class SiteListViewModel
{
    public ICommand AddBtnOnClickCommand { get; }
    private ICommand _selectBtnOnClickCommand;
    public ICommand SelectBtnOnClickCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_selectBtnOnClickCommand == null)
                _selectBtnOnClickCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
                {
                    var selectedSites = (o as IList);
                    if (selectedSites != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var model in selectedSites.OfType<SiteUrlsModel>())
                        {
                            //
                        }
                    }
                });
            return _selectBtnOnClickCommand;
        }
    }

    private readonly IWindowService _windowService;
    public static SiteUrlsModel SiteUrlsModel { get; } = new SiteUrlsModel();
    public ObservableCollection<SiteUrlsModel> SelectedSites { get; set; }
    private readonly ClientContext _clientContext = new ClientContext();


    public SiteListViewModel(IWindowService windowService)
    {
        _windowService = windowService;
        AddBtnOnClickCommand = new RelayCommand(AddBtnOnClick);
        //SelectBtnOnClickCommand = new RelayCommand(SelectBtnOnClick);
        RefreshSiteListView();
    }

    public void AddBtnOnClick()
    {
        _addSiteWindow = new AddSite(this);
        _addSiteWindow.Show();
    }

    public void SelectBtnOnClick(ObservableCollection<SiteUrlsModel> checkedList)
    {
        foreach (var site in checkedList)
        {
            site.IsChecked = true;
        }
    }    

    public void RefreshSiteListView()
    {
        var siteUrlsCollection = new ObservableCollection<SiteUrlsModel>(_clientContext.PopulateList());
        SiteUrlsModel.SiteUrlsCollection = siteUrlsCollection;
    }       
}
```

### CommandClass

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {

        private readonly Action<object> _actionWithObject;

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> actionWithObject)
        {
            _actionWithObject = actionWithObject;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            if (parameter != null)
                _actionWithObject(parameter);
            else
                _actionWithObject(parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    }
```

Comment: Not what you were asking, but.... Rather than using your own implementation of relaycommand, I suggest you use the one in mvvmlight. You can then find loads of examples of using that. And the commandparameter would be strongly typed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListView.SelectedItems` is an `IList`:

```
private ICommand _selectBtnOnClickCommand;
public ICommand SelectBtnOnClickCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_selectBtnOnClickCommand == null)
            _selectBtnOnClickCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
            {
                var selectedSites = (o as IList);
                if (selectedSites != null)
                {
                    foreach (var model in selectedSites.OfType<SiteUrlsModel>())
                    {
                        //
                    }
                }
            });
        return _selectBtnOnClickCommand;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am more focused on getting the code to be hit and seeing it populated in debug mode though, sorry if my code does not set things properly into context but as the command is just a property it is not in the constructor like the rest of my commands. I want to know how to set it to the list that it has received. e.g. `SelectBtnOnClickCommand = new RelayCommand(SelectBtnOnClick(mylist));`

Comment: It gets hit but only when the class is being instantiated. After that it does not trigger a command when the button is clicked. My other commands are in my constructor but they are basic and do not handle any parameters.

Comment: When the class is being instantiated...? Are you really executing the command then? What's the DataContext of the Button? Please post your full view model code.

Comment: The DataContext of the View is the ViewModel, so i suppose to answer you its the viewmodel. ViewModel being the one I represented above, thanks.

Comment: I have done that now, I didn't because I simply wanted to show what was essential for my question, rather than show a bunch of unrelated functions, thanks.

Comment: Did you put the breakpoint *in the delegate* that you pass to the command? Please also post the markup of your view including how you set the DataContext of it.

Comment: I did, and like I said it does get hit, but that is when the DataContext is being set at the start to a new instance of my ViewModel, i select records *after* the application has loaded and then click the button, at that point no the command isn't fired by clicking the button

Comment: Then you have put the breakpoint on the wrong line. Setting the DataContext doesn't execute the command...what if you display a MessageBox in the command?

Comment: Excellent suggestion, the messagebox showed up! But I can confirm my breakpoint was within the parentheses of the get{}, not sure why it did not stop there.

Comment: @mm8 this might work, but VM should never have any logic. Steve you should read about SOLID :)

Comment: @JuanCarlosRodriguez lol... wut?? That's where you're supposed to put the logic.

Comment: @SledgeHammer the VM adapts the model to the view. Command execution and command initialization should be in another class. By doing this, this is neither maintainable nor opened to modification. You should have a SiteListViewModelCommandManager where you define your command's execution and a SiteListViewModelFactory/SiteListViewModelInitializer where you set your command instance. What would you do if you have the same command for 2 VM ? Duplicate the code to write the same logic in both VM ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosRodriguez That's an edge case. Not the norm. How I would solve it depends on the situation. CompositeCommand, base class, messenger, etc. I wouldn't just randomly do it for every command ever created. That's dumb.